# XSLT (1.0): comparing substring-after to attribute value fails

Tags: xslt

maybe I have overlooked something really obvious, but at the moment I'm really at a loss. I am trying to get a node by comparing its attribute `@ID` to the result of a call to `substring-before`. While this fails, manually entering the string gives the right result and I am really puzzled where the problem is.
There are no whitespaces interfering and the result of `substring-before()` is exactly what I want.

I have the following snippet in a file `mets.xml`:

```
<mets:file ID="edoc_ed000227_fg_kuttenberger_religionsfriede" MIMETYPE="text/xml">
    <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="quellentexte/kuttenberger_religionsfriede.xml"/>
</mets:file>
```

The file to which I apply the transformation has this basic outline:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" 
    xml:id="edoc_ed000227_fg_kuttenberger_religionsfriede_dt">
    [...]
    <p xml:id="p001">[...]</p>
</TEI>
```

I now apply the following transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:p[@xml:id]">
    <xsl:variable name="test" select="substring-before(/tei:TEI/@xml:id, '_dt')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="target" select="document($metsfile)//mets:file[@ID=substring-before(/tei:TEI/@xml:id, '_dt')]/mets:FLocat/@xlink:href"/>
    <xsl:variable name="target2" select="document($metsfile)//mets:file[@ID='edoc_ed000227_fg_kuttenberger_religionsfriede']/mets:FLocat/@xlink:href"/>
    [<xsl:value-of select="$test"/>]
    [<xsl:value-of select="$target"/>]
    [<xsl:value-of select="$target2"/>]
</xsl:template>
```

And I get

```
    [edoc_ed000227_fg_kuttenberger_religionsfriede]
    []
    [quellentexte/kuttenberger_religionsfriede.xml]
```

So, `substring-before()` correctly returns `edoc_ed000227_fg_kuttenberger_religionsfriede` yet using the function call to retrieve the target value fails even though the node is correctly found when using the string literally.

Thanks for any help or hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression you use in the substring-before, for the `target` variable will be in the context of the "mets" file. That is to say, it will look for `tei:TEI` in the mets file, not in the current document.

As you have already stored the substring-before value in a variable; "test", you can use that in the expression instead.

```
<xsl:variable name="target" select="document($metsfile)//mets:file[@ID=$test]/mets:FLocat/@xlink:href"/>
```

Comment: *headdesk* good grief, I should have seen that myself...
I usually don't use variables for stuff I only need once – `current()/ancestor::tei:TEI/@xml:id` would have been the way without a variable. Thanks!